# ShinyProxy Euler App not running - Failed to start container

Tags: r, linux, docker, shiny, shinyproxy

I am new to docker and ShinyProxy. I was following the steps from https://www.shinyproxy.io/. All is working fine with the Hello-world and 06_tabset apps. Then I have build the Image for the Euler App which is not working when opening the app from the browser.

```
Error
Status code: 500

Message: Failed to start container

Stack Trace: 
eu.openanalytics.containerproxy.ContainerProxyException: Failed to start container
```

**EDIT:**

The actual error is:

```
 Caused by: com.spotify.docker.client.exceptions.DockerRequestException: Request error: POST http://localhost:2375/containers/create: 400, body: {"message":"No command specified"}
```

also when I try to just run the App it is not working with:

```
sudo docker run -p 3838:3838 openanalytics/shinyproxy-demo R -e 'shiny::runApp('/root/euler')'
```

the Error I get is:

```
shiny::runApp(/root/euler)
Error: unexpected '/' in "shiny::runApp(/"
Execution halted
```

and after changing it to:

```
sudo docker run -p 3838:3838 openanalytics/shinyproxy-demo R -e 'shiny::runApp('root/euler')'
```

I get this:

```
Error in as.shiny.appobj(appDir) : object 'root' not found
Calls: <Anonymous> -> as.shiny.appobj
Execution halted
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem could be that the Image is openanalytics/shinyproxy-template and not openanalytics/shinyproxy-demo.

try:

```
 sudo docker run -p 3838:3838 openanalytics/shinyproxy-template R -e 'shiny::runApp("/root/euler")'
```

Comment: now it is working outside of ShinyProxy but the
 
Error
Status code: 500

Message: Failed to start container

is still there :(

Answer (score 1):

just try this :

```
sudo docker run -p 3838:3838 openanalytics/shinyproxy-demo R -e 'shiny::runApp("/root/euler")'
```

the problem is that you use `'` twice in your command that is why the app sees that as `'shiny::runApp(/'`

and make sure that Shiny application exists at the path "/root/euler".

Comment: please see EDIT